# How is Johnson's shortest path weighting function $\hat{w}(u, v) = w(u, v) + h(u) - h(v)$ proven by the triangular inequility?

Tags: shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Recap to the Johnson's shortest path algorithm:

By the procedure extending the original graph $G^\prime = (V^\prime, E^\prime), V^\prime = V\ \cup \{s\}, E^\prime = E\ \cup \{(s, v)\ |\ \forall v \in V\}$, and then extend the original weighting function $\forall x \in V,\ w(s, x) = 0.$

Finally define the **reweighted** function $\hat{w}(u, v) = w(u, v) + h(u) - h(v)$ where $\forall x \in V,\ h(x) = d(s, x)$ , where $d(s, x)$ is the shortest path from $s$ to $x$.

Problem:

Assume that there is no negative cycle in the graph. The textbook [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) says that
$w(u, v) + h(u) - h(v)$ is always **nonnegative** proven by using the **triangular inequality theorem** to get $w(u, v) + h(u) \ge h(v)$.

This makes me so confused, because **I think that there could exist negative weights in the graph and hence triangular inequality can't be applied.** (Am I misunderstanding triangular inequality? Or something are skipped I cannot tell?).

Where did I misunderstand about this algorithm? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you can't (necessarily) apply the triangle inequality to the edges of the original graph, but that's not what's being discussed here.

We know $h(u)$ is, by definition, the shortest path to $u$.  Thus we immediately know that $w(u,v) + h(u) \geq h(v)$ because, if it wasn't true, $h(v)$ would not be the shortest path to $v$.  The author is calling this the "triangle inequality" of the reweighted graph.

Comment: Do you mean because $h(v)$ is the shortest distance from $s$ to $v$, and $w(u, v) + h(u)$ forms the distance of another path from $s$ to $v$ thus the inequality must hold?

Comment: @OODWaterball: Yes, exactly